# Is there a reason a thread would only execute when I force it to in debug?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, debugging

I have an issue trying to send data to a database. I have the main thread opening a new thread for the connection, then a sql statement runs and inserts a row into a database in the background while the UI switches to another activity (which is a camera activity). The issue is when running normally, the thread doesn't seem to execute but when running in debug and stepping through each line of the ASyncTask, it does. The only time database is being updated is when I step through in debug. The database is on a Microsoft SQL Server.

I've tried this multiple times and the thread consistently only executes when I force it to by stepping through in debug.

In the main thread

```
SendToDB sendFalsePositive = new SendToDB();
sendFalsePositive.execute();
```

The AsyncTask being executed

```
Connection conn;

        try {
//          com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            // jdbc and jtds are the drivers that allow the connection to outside databases
            // sq41ddb.na.steelcase.net:3250 is the server and port that are need to connect to the scrapMinder database
            String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SQLSERVER;databaseName=DATABASENAME;user=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD";

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);

            Log.i("Connection", "Open");
            Log.i("SEND TO DB", "Date: " + date + " Time: " +time);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            statement.executeUpdate("Insert Into DATABASENAME (Date, Time) \n" +
                    "values ('" + date + "', '" + time +"' );"); //SQL SELECT STATEMENT TO INSERT INTO DATABASE 
            statement.setQueryTimeout(0);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error SendToDB", e.toString());
        }
```

Is there a way to force this thread to execute?

Comment: Are you saying, the very first line of the function in question is never reached? How have you verified this?

Comment: My guess would be the AsyncTask is destroyed when its hosting activity is destroyed as you switch activities.  I think you'll want a service to accomplish this.

Comment: Verified by running the query on my database and not seeing the data that's supposed be sent. On a full speed run, I'm not sure that the first line of that function is ever touched. I think nasch may be right here, I have another insert running to the same database on another activity that doesn't get destroyed as quick, but it executes fine

Comment: @nasch good catch! Can you explain what the mechanism of the loss is? GC? Process death? Why would an AsyncTask know/care that an Activity had gone away?

Comment: It's not just an activity, it's the context in which the AsyncTask is running.  So when the activity is destroyed, the system stops the task as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess would be the AsyncTask is destroyed when its hosting activity is destroyed as you switch activities. I think you'll want a service to accomplish this.

This was the issue. The AsyncTasks were being removed when the activity switched causing the SQL to never get executed. I added a new activity and called the function in it and the SQL is now being executed. Thanks for the tip nasch!